# Java loop required

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm quite new to coding, as you all can see from the clumsy code below. However, looking at this code you can see what I'm getting at. The code basically does what its supposed to, but I would like to write it as a loop to make it more efficient. Could someone maybe point me in the right direction? I have done some digging and thought about recursion, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply it here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double a = 10;
    double b = 2;
    double c = 3;
    double avg = (a + b + c)/3;
    double avg1 = (avg + b + c)/3;
    double avg2 = (avg1 + b + c)/3;
    double avg3 = (avg2 + b + c)/3;
    System.out.println(avg+ "\n" + avg1+ "\n"+ avg2 + "\n"+ avg3);

}
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Hint: you want to calculate `avg` first and then loop 3 times. On each itteration you want to calculate `(previous result + b + c) /3`. Hope this helps...

Comment: You should explain what your code is supposed to do so we can give you a solution.

Comment: I have to agree with @Gianlucca. Without knowing what your ultimate aim is with regard to this calculation, it's not clear what is the best way to achieve it. It looks a little like brute force is being used right now, when there might be a more elegant solution to calculate the answer you seek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, this would be equivalent to what you have done:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double a = 10;
    double b = 2;
    double c = 3;
    double avg = (a + b + c)/3;

    System.out.println(avg);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        avg = (avg + b + c)/3;
        System.out.println(avg);
    }

}
```

But also you should know that shorter code does not always mean efficient code. The solution may be more concise, but I doubt there will be any change in performance.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This was exactly what I wanted to achieve. Is the first System.out.println(avg); the first line I see in the output and then we enter the loop?

Comment: Correct. If this answer is satisfactory, can you accept it as the correct answer?

Comment: This does answer the original request for a loop which achieves the desired result, but I still recommend using the direct, single calculation approach suggested in my answer. Looping (and especially recursion) should be avoided whenever possible if efficiency is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean shorter code with efficieny you can do it like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 10;
    double b = 2;
    double c = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        a = (a + b + c) / 3;
        System.out.println(a);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this calculation represents (some sort of specialised weighted average?) but rather than use repetition and loops, you can reach the exact same calculation by using a bit of algebra and refactoring the terms:

```java
public static double directlyCalculateWeightedAverage(double a, double b,
        double c) {
    return a / 81 + 40 * b / 81 + 40 * c / 81;
}
```

This reformulation is reached because the factor `a` appears just once in the mix and is then divided by 3<sup>4</sup> which is 81. Then each of `b` and `c` appear at various levels of division, so that `b` sums to this:

```
b/81 + b/27 + b/9 + b/3
== b/81 + 3b/81 + 9b/81 + 27b/81
== 40b/81
```

and `c` is treated exactly the same.

Which gives the direct calculation

```
a/81 + 40b/81 + 40c/81
```

Assuming your formula does not change, I'd recommend using this direct approach rather than resorting to repeated calculations and loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by 2 approaches: iterative (with a loop) or recursive (with a recursive function).

#### Iterative approach : for loop

The for loop allow you to repeat a group of instructions au given number of times.
In your case, you could write the following :

```
double a = 10, b = 2, c = 3;
double avg = a;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    avg = (avg + b + c) / 3;
    System.out.println(avg);
}
```

This will print the 4 first results of your calculation.
In my example, I overwrite the variable `avg` to only keep the last result, which might not be what you want. To keep the result of each loop iteration, you may store the result in an array.

#### Recursive approach

In Java, there is no such thing as a standalone function. In order to use recursion, you have to use static methods :

```
private static double recursiveAvg(double avg, int count) {
    // Always check that the condition for your recursion is valid !
    if (count == 0) {
        return avg;
    }

    // Apply your formula
    avg = (avg + 2 + 3) / 3;

    // Call the same function with the new avg value, and decrease the iteration count.
    return recursiveAvg(avg, count - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Start from a = 10, and repeat the operation 4 times.
    double avg = recursiveAvg(10, 4);
    System.out.println(avg);
}
```

Always check for a condition that will end the recursion. In our example, it's the number of times the operation should be performed.

Note that most programmers prefer the iterative approach : easier to write and read, and less error prone.